# How to create a link tag cloud

Tags: html, css

I need to generate a text link cloud something like the image attached.
As some words are vertical, I am thinking of doing it via CSS3. But it is consuming lot of time.

Do you know any website or any better idea of how I can do it fast?

I am using transform property.

[image]

Comment: Is this what are you looking for [tag cloud](http://www.tagcloud-generator.com) ?

Comment: yes... with horizontal and vertical links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of websites:

http://www.edudemic.com/9-word-cloud-generators-that-arent-wordle/

http://www.wordle.net/

http://www.tagxedo.com/app.html

http://www.tagcloud-generator.com/

http://tagcrowd.com/

http://www.tagcloudgenerator.com/

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I like this one, http://www.tagxedo.com/app.html ... .TFS :)

Comment: no problem, just googled :)

Comment: Waste of time: tagxedo requires Silverlight, and can't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The `0nline Image Map Editor` May helps you to create a link

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap