# Add different styles (tagcloud/linkcloud) to hyperlinks at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I need to create simple link display like below image;
[image]

What I thought is add separate styles for all of these links. but its looks not the best way to do this.

have anyone tried something like this? can I do this with JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: If you want it to look exactly like that, defining separate styles is definitely the best way.

Comment: This looks pretty much like a tagcloud/linkcloud to me. How about using a jQuery plugin like http://addywaddy.github.io/jquery.tagcloud.js/

Comment: Well, you have to assign different styles to each one, otherways each link looks exactly the same. but what you can do is f.e. put each link into a class and loop through that class using js or jq. You could then randomly assign attributes. F.e. if the link is at child position 2 or 4, set the font size to 20 else to 16. You could also make a good use of css3 "new" selectors. F.e. :nth-child() see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css  I hope this points you into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks all.. and @supersize you've saved my hours! thank you verymuch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows you to randomly position the Text. Maybe you could edit it slightly for your needs?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
   body {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      height: 300px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 300px;
   }
 
   .box {
      height: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      width: auto;
   }
   
   #div1 { background:0;color:red; }
   #div2 { background:0;color:blue; }
   #div3 { background:0; color:green;}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function setDivPos() {
      for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
         var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*250);
         var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*250);
         document.getElementById('div'+i).style.left = x + 'px';
         document.getElementById('div'+i).style.top = y + 'px';
      }
   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='setDivPos();'>
<div id='div1' class='box'>one word</div>
<div id='div2' class='box'>another word</div>
<div id='div3' class='box'>and so on</div>
</body>
</html>
Anyone have time to help?
```

## Alternative

An alternative to this would be: [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rQLST/9/)

## Links:

There are several links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21577290/3913686) that you might be interested in

Comment: np. If there's anything else you were looking for(other than a fully operational demo :P ) sure you can give me a shout